# How to hide updates in Windows Updates without GUI

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

When you don't want to update a particular windows update one can do that by following steps on windows 7 below:

1. Open Windows Updates
2. Click on View Updates
3. Right click on the item you want to hide
4. Click on Hide

But I want to know how to do it without using GUI. So I can apply to multiple pc.
How does windows 7 save the info of hidden update? is it by Registry?
Can we actually replace those 4 steps by one simple Registry file?
Or some sort Windows script?

Comment: why have you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: That's not my intension. I have put it back. This is the answer I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An user posted a VBscript (HideKBs_BingDesktop.vbs) [on msfn.org which hides updates](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/163162-hide-bing-desktop-and-other-windows-updates/).

```
' Maxpsoft May 30, 2013, 9:34:15 PM
' 06/18/2013 Add extra for Bing Desktop v1.3
' 06/28/2013 Updated to continue searching as long as it is finding something otherwise Quit
'
' Original Mike.Moore Dec 17, 2012 on answers.microsoft but when ran it Hide everything so no good.
' Link to script: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/163162-hide-bing-desktop-and-other-windows-updates/
' You may freely use this script as long as you copy it complete and it remains the same except for adjusting hideupdates.
' If I need to change something then let me know so all may benefit.

Dim WSHShell, StartTime, ElapsedTime, strUpdateName, strAllHidden
Dim Checkagain 'Find more keep going otherwise Quit

Dim hideupdates(3) 'TO ADD 1 EDIT THE (3) AND ADD another hideupdates(#)

hideupdates(0) = "KB2592687" 'Remote Desktop Protocol 8.0
hideupdates(1) = "KB2709981" 'Windows Media Player 12
hideupdates(2) = "Bing Desktop" 'With this we get all versions
hideupdates(3) = "Silverlight"

Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

StartTime = Timer 'Start the Timer

Set updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
updateSession.ClientApplicationID = "MSDN Sample Script"
Set updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
Set searchResult = updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software' and IsHidden=0")

Checkagain = "True"

For K = 0 To 10 'Bing Desktop has 4, Silverlight has 5
If Checkagain = "True" Then
Checkagain = "False"
CheckUpdates
ParseUpdates
End if
Next

ElapsedTime = Timer - StartTime
strTitle = "Bing Desktop and Windows Updates Hidden."
strText = strAllHidden
strText = strText & vbCrLf & ""
strText = strText & vbCrLf & "Total Time " & ElapsedTime
intType = vbOkOnly

'Silent just comment these 2 lines with a ' and it will run and quit
Set objWshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
intResult = objWshShell.Popup(strText, ,strTitle, intType)

'Open Windows Update after remove the comment '
'WshShell.Run "%windir%\system32\control.exe /name Microsoft.WindowsUpdate"

Set objWshShell = nothing
Set WSHShell = Nothing
WScript.Quit


Function ParseUpdates 'cycle through updates
For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
strUpdateName = update.Title
'WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> " & update.Title
For j = 0 To UBound(hideupdates)
if instr(1, strUpdateName, hideupdates(j), vbTextCompare) = 0 then
Else
strAllHidden = strAllHidden _
& vbcrlf & update.Title
update.IsHidden = True'
Checkagain = "True"
end if
Next
Next
End Function

Function CheckUpdates 'check for new updates cause Bing Desktop has 3
Set updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
updateSession.ClientApplicationID = "MSDN Sample Script"
Set updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
Set searchResult = _
updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software' and IsHidden=0")
End Function
```

Edit the hideupdates array as written in the script and add the KB number you want to hide.

Comment: Although, I have no idea why 'Set objWshShell = nothing' & 'Set WSHShell = Nothing' cause error on my Windows 7 x64 system but after I comment out those two line, it worked like a charm. Thanks for this brilliant answer!!

Comment: hi @magicandre1981 I do not know how to "accept" answer until now. thanks anyway.