# Prevent Windows 10 nag updates from being installed on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

During their Windows 10 blitz, some blockhead at Microsoft thought it would be a [great idea](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2906810/microsoft-seeds-windows-7-81-pcs-with-windows-10-upgrade-nag-notices.html) to push out "nag" marketing messages to Windows 7 users, under the guise of Windows Updates.  To make matters worse, it took them a [few tries](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2922604/microsoft-windows/microsoft-re-re-re-issues-controversial-windows-10-advertising-patch-kb-3035583.html) to get it right, resulting in several related patches which might be shown.

When I install new Windows 7 SP1 computers from scratch (and yes, there are still legitimate reasons for doing so), what's the **quickest and easiest** way to prevent these unwanted "updates" from ever getting applied in the first place?

Comment: This post is not meant to be a criticism of Windows 10 or to spark a why-I-should-upgrade discussion.  I'm simply looking for a way to permanently disable the nags.

Answer (score 2):

I found some manual steps [here](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/04/17/how-to-remove-windows-10-upgrade-updates-in-windows-7-and-8/) and [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/windows-7-to-10-gwx-how-to-remove.html), and attempted to automate them using the dirty-and-not-so-quick script below (based on [this](https://superuser.com/a/722679/75522)).  But it takes over half an hour to run and I'm leaving the question open in hopes someone can suggest a more convenient solution.

```
Dim msg
msg = "Searching for and hiding six Windows Updates related to Windows 10 nagging." & vbCrLf
msg = msg & "Be patient; this may take a LONG time during which nothing appears to happen."
msg = msg & " You can tell the script is still running by using Task Manager and looking for wscript.exe"
Wscript.echo msg

Dim hideupdates(5)
hideupdates(0) = "KB3035583"
hideupdates(1) = "KB2952664"
hideupdates(2) = "KB2976978"
hideupdates(3) = "KB3021917"
hideupdates(4) = "KB3044374"
hideupdates(5) = "KB2990214"

Dim status(5)
For i = 0 to UBound(status)
  status(i) = "notfound"
Next

set updateSession = createObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
set updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()

Set searchResult = updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'")

dim results
Set results = searchResult.Updates
For i = 0 To results.Count-1
  set update = results.Item(i)
  For j = LBound(hideupdates) To UBound(hideupdates)
    if instr(1, update.Title, hideupdates(j), vbTextCompare) > 0 then
      if update.IsHidden then
        status(j) = "alreadyhidden"
      else
        update.IsHidden = True
        status(j) = "hidden"
      end if
    end if
  Next
Next

Dim alreadyhidden
Dim hidden
Dim notfound

for i = 0 to UBound(status)
  Select Case status(i)
    Case "alreadyhidden"
      alreadyhidden = alreadyhidden & hideupdates(i) & vbCrLf
    Case "notfound"
      notfound = notfound & hideupdates(i) & vbCrLf
    Case "hidden"
      hidden = hidden & hideupdates(i) & vbCrLf
  End Select
next
msg = "Hid these Windows 10 related updates:" & vbCrLf
msg = msg & hidden & vbCrLf
msg = msg & "These ones were already hidden:" & vbCrLf
msg = msg & alreadyhidden & vbCrLf
msg = msg & "These ones were not found on this machine:" & vbCrLf
msg = msg & notfound

Wscript.echo msg
```

[image: 5]]

Answer (score 0):

Quote rkagerer **"what's the quickest and easiest way to prevent these unwanted "updates" from ever getting applied in the first place?"** If you are doing a fresh install than

***"Uncheck Recommended updates (Optional) in windows update settings."***

It reads Give me recommended updates the same way i receive important updates. Afterwards you can individually check recommended updates those you wants to install if any. I don't recommend installing each recommended updates thrown by MS. Recently it created more mess than good.