# How to install security updates after "Upgrade to Windows 10" hijacks Windows Update?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, malware, windows-10-upgrade

***EDIT***: Future visitors - the cited duplicate is not a duplicate. Ignore Ramhound's (and other's) claims. This is not a question about removing Get Windows 10 malware because it keeps returning. Instead, its a question about installing the security updates after  Get Windows 10 malware hijacks the update process.

---

Patch Tuesday was yesterday. My Windows 7 machine took about 10 or 15 security updates. I attempted to install the updates on my mother's Windows 7 machine, but it appears `GWX.exe` has returned. The malware has gotten more aggressive, and it has hijacked the Windows Update process. (I've already removed it completely twice).

[image]

I visited ***Show all available updates*** and selected all the updates. But when I clicked ***Ok*** and returned to install screen, the malware was still controlling the screen, and there was no ***Install updates*** like I am used to seeing.

I also clicked the ***Get Started*** button (with an immediate exit) hoping I could dismiss the malware, but it did not return control of the update process to me.

How do I install the outstanding Windows Updates?

Comment: Did you try this? http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/disabling-windows-10-upgrade-notification

Comment: [Prevent Windows 10 nag updates from being installed on Windows 7](http://superuser.com/q/954491)

Answer (score 1):

> How do I install outstanding Windows Updates?

In the main Windows Update window  [image]
left click the blue `Show all available updates`.

---

[image]
Left click on **Optional ()** on far left side of the Windows Update window.

---

That should reveal a check-marked selection for the Windows 10 Upgrade (which is the cause of your anguish).[image]

### Uncheck that selection (to disable the upgrade).

Proceed to select any optional updates.
Left click on **Important ()** on far left side of the Windows Update window.
Select the Important updates.
Resume the normal update procedure (e.g. click the **OK** button on the bottom right, then at the main screen click the **Install updates** button).

---

<s>After you reboot and start Windows Update again, the Upgrade WIndows 10 will self-activate again.

Right-clicking the update line for Win10 and hiding it does not seem to disable this update.</s>

**ADDENDUM**
As of this moment, the Windows 10 Upgrade no longer appears in the list of available updates on my PCs.  No patches, registry edits or removed updates have been made.  The icon for the upgrade is still in the system tray.
IOW the removal must be on the MS server end.