# What are all the Windows 7/8/8.1 updates (KBs) I must skip to avoid Windows 10 upgrading -and nags-?

Tags: windows, windows-update

It's been a time I didn't follow the list of which Windows 7/8/8.1 KBs I must skip since I don't want the unfinished Windows 10 at all. Moreover, I will still consider Windows 10 unfinished (-> unstable) until they release Windows Server 2016

The KBs list up today is scattered all over the Internet, and I am fearing to miss a single one of those.  As far as I know, some of the newer KBs are even old rebranded ones or re-re-re-pushed again and again.
The goal is also to not use any external software or post-installation removal tools since I also intend to deploy a script that will block those KBs.

So the question is: can you tell me all the KBs you know that I must avoid? 
Any details that can prevent "Telemetry", the "Windows Customer Experience Improvement Program" or prevent the resetting of Windows' settings about updates and privacy concerns is good too ! (Since they are even linked)

In case some cumulative updates (updates that regroup a pack of old ones) contains one of the listed KB, this is still relevant for the question here.

**Remarks**

There is of course other ways to disable the updates, which are still appreciated here but do consider that they represent a secondary objective of this post.
Same applies for saying it's not the correct method to do it, and I do know the list will endlessly get longer.

The reason is that I still prefer doing it manually since I don't even want the files at all in my system. Furthermore, some of these updates had been re-pushed again and again for at least six times ! This is in fact due to the problems that those updates had caused and I don't want any risks to jeopardize my systems because Microsoft have plans for users with our without their consent by doing "*Betas To Manufacture*".

related: [How to disable the "Get Windows 10" icon shown in the notification area (tray)?](https://superuser.com/questions/922068/how-to-disable-the-get-windows-10-icon-shown-in-the-notification-area-tray)

Comment: i f you want to answer your own question, add an answer. Don't include an answer in the question and keep editing/changing the answer part.

Comment: Just a note that this is the *wrong approach* to the problem, kind of like asking "my trunk door keeps rattling, what is the serial number of every part of the trunk door and/or tail light assembly, so that I can remove them and stop the rattle?" Worse, the list changes over time, so no answer given can remain correct for long. A better answer is to install software that handles this task for you, such as "GWX Control Panel". That way, you centralize the task of keeping track, updating the list, and managing the problem.

Comment: The telemetry part of the question is answered (by me) here [How to stop Microsoft from gathering telemetry data from Windows 7, 8, and 8.1](http://superuser.com/a/972506)

Comment: (Can we please remove the "comments" from the question). You have a question, the question is clear, it really shouldn't need any more significant changes.  The question has changed significantly, from the original revision, with the introduction of the Server product line to the question.

Comment: You might want to remove the ranting from your question. I don't think your reasons for not wanting the upgrade are really relevant to the actual question. And you should only really ask one question at a time - if you want to disable CEI, ask another question (or better, use the search option, since it's already answered :) ). Just don't complain when Windows removes your favourite feature because of skewed usage data :P

Comment: Windows 10 will still be unfinished long after Server 2016 is released. In fact it will be unfinished forever. You may as well claim your free upgrade while you still can, and then immediately roll back (you get 30 days to do this) if you're determined not to use it. Your digital entitlement remains active and you can upgrade again whenever you wish.

Comment: Luuan: Microsoft didn't used any unskewed data for transforming Windows for Desktop to a Windows for Tablets...
Michael Hampton: The reason why Windows Server often rolls out after a regular Windows is that the new implemented technologies included in the latter are not completely stable for a situation where "permanent service" is required, which means enough stability. By the way, I will take the free upgrade and then cleanly backup Windows 10 then rollback to Windows 7 thanks to Boot to VHD.

Comment: I will ask again.  Can we please remove the comments and rant from the question?

Comment: I'm ok as long as it don't make people flood again and again "there's a better solution", since it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: X.LINK what tool you use to block all the updates? I am interesting in using the same solution as you.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Last updated (all dates here are DD-MM-YYYY): 12/03/2016 @ 00:18 GMT

/!\ Warning ! Even if the list is starting to get very exhaustive, **some of the updates for Windows 8.1 still contains GWX** outside the infamous KB3035583.
The concerned updates were in the "**optional**" and "**recommended**" sections of Windows Update -"important" updates were almost safe-, and the time span is between **02/08/2015** and **12/03/2016**. Please watch the **Suspected List** down here /!\

Please be aware that some updates that were designed for specific version of Windows -e.g. "exclusively" for 7, 8, 8.1, Server 2008 R2, Server 2012 or Server 2012 R2- are even pushed to all of them ! So everything counts.

The List for Windows 10 upgrade:

```
KB 30 355 83   ->   The "GWX" nagware, often updated and re-re-re-pushed

KB 31 399 29   ->   Security update for Internet Explorer, re-pushed again

KB 31 464 49   ->   Included in KB 3139929 !!! The Internet Explorer W10 ad.

KB 30 443 74   ->   KB3035583 linked ! Upgrade to Windows 10 for Windows 8.1

KB 29 902 14   ->   KB3035583 linked ! Update Win 7 to a "newer Windows"

KB 29 526 64   ->   KB3035583 linked ! Re-re-re-pushed; eases Win 10 upgrade
```

The List for "telemetry"/"Windows Customer Experience Improvement Program":

```
KB 29 769 78   ->   KB3035583 linked ! Check "Win 10 upgrade for Win 8"

KB 30 752 49   ->   KB3035583 linked ! "Telemetry", points to "consent.exe"

KB 30 801 49   ->   KB3035583 linked ! "Customer Exp and Diag Telemetry"

KB 30 219 17   ->   KB3035583 linked ! "Customer Exp and Diag Telemetry"

KB 30 223 45   ->   KB3035583 linked ! "Customer Exp and Diag Telemetry"

KB 30 687 08   ->   KB3035583 linked ! "Customer Exp and Diag Telemetry"

KB 30 129 73   ->   KB3035583 linked ! Windows 10 force upgrade installer


KB 29 777 59   ->   Re-re-re-pushed; Telemetry for Windows 10 upgrade

KB 97 10 33    ->   (Yes, only 6 digits)

KB 30 659 88   ->   "Update" for Windows Update on Win 8.1 and Svr 2012 R2

KB 30 833 25   ->   "Update" for Windows Update on Win 8.1 and Svr 2012 R2

KB 30 833 24   ->   "Update" for Windows Update on Win 7 and Svr 2008 R2

KB 30 758 53   ->   "Update" for Windows Update on Win 8.1 and Svr 2012 R2

KB 30 659 87   ->   "Update" for Windows Update on Win 7 and Svr 2008 R2

KB 30 502 65   ->   "Update" for Windows Update on Win 7

KB 30 502 67   ->   "Update" for Windows Update on Win 8.1

KB 30 758 51   ->   "Update" for Windows Update on Win 7 and Svr 2008 R2

KB 29 029 07   ->   "MS Security Essentials/Windows Defender", no details

KB 30 464 80   ->   When upgrading Win 7 or 8, determines .Net 1.1 migration

KB 30 833 24   ->   "Update" for Windows Update on Win 7 and Svr 2008 R2

KB 30 833 25   ->   "Update" for Windows Update on Win 8.1 and Svr 2012 R2

KB 30 837 10   ->   "Update" for Windows Update on Win 7 and Svr 2008 R2

KB 30 837 11   ->   "Update" for Windows Update on Win 8.1 and Svr 2012 R2

KB 31 123 36   ->   "Update" for Windows Update on Win 8.1 and Svr 2012 R2
```

Despite disabling the "telemetry"'s KBs, there's still things to do specifically for that here : [How to stop Microsoft from gathering telemetry data from Windows 7, 8, and 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/972501/how-to-stop-microsoft-from-gathering-telemetry-data-from-windows-7-8-and-8-1/)

The List for "Suspected Updates":

```
KB 31 242 80   ->   The only "Important update" suspected

KB 31 036 96

KB 31 212 60

KB 30 998 34

KB 30 849 05

KB 30 296 06

KB 31 348 15

KB 31 399 21

KB 31 260 30

KB 30 607 46

KB 31 024 29

KB 30 926 27

KB 30 808 00

KB 30 784 05

KB 30 800 42

KB 31 036 99

KB 31 009 56

KB 30 544 64

KB 30 614 93

KB 31 339 24

KB 30 607 93

KB 30 638 43

KB 30 720 19

KB 31 260 33

KB 30 957 01

KB 30 563 47

KB 31 009 19

KB 31 232 42

KB 30 793 18

KB 30 184 67

KB 31 238 62

KB 30 137 91

KB 30 786 76

KB 30 593 16

KB 30 457 46

KB 31 286 50

KB 30 553 43

KB 31 184 01

KB 30 716 63

KB 30 912 97

KB 30 964 33

KB 30 355 83

KB 30 456 34

KB 30 650 13

KB 31 252 10

KB 30 296 03

KB 30 294 32

KB 30 538 63

KB 31 121 48

KB 30 640 59

KB 30 603 83

KB 30 870 41

KB 31 212 55

KB 30 542 56

KB 31 079 98

KB 31 212 61

KB 30 418 57

KB 30 871 37

KB 31 320 80

KB 31 308 96

KB 30 581 68

KB 30 553 23
```

To speed up the process of uninstalling all these Updates use wusa in command prompt. or drop the below code into notepad and name it "uninstall.bat"

/quiet - No verbose

/norestart - do not restart the computer

```
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3035583
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3139929
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3146449
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3044374
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:2990214
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:2952664
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:2976978
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3075249
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3080149
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3021917
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3022345
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3068708
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3012973
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:2977759
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:971033
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3065988
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3083325
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3083324
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3075853
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3065987
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3050265
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3050267
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3075851
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:2902907
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3046480
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3083324
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3083325
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3083710
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3083711
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3112336
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3124280
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3103696
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3121260
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3099834
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3084905
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3029606
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3134815
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3139921
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3126030
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3060746
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3102429
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3092627
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3080800
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3078405
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3080042
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3103699
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3100956
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3054464
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3061493
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3133924
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3060793
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3063843
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3072019
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3126033
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3095701
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3056347
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3100919
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3123242
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3079318
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3018467
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3123862
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3013791
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3078676
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3059316
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3045746
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3128650
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3055343
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3118401
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3071663
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3091297
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3096433
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3035583
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3045634
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3065013
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3125210
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3029603
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3029432
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3053863
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3112148
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3064059
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3060383
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3087041
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3121255
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3054256
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3107998
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3121261
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3041857
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3087137
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3132080
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3130896
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3058168
wusa /quiet /uninstall /norestart /KB:3055323
```

Sources:

- Me
- The SuperUser's people
- https://fix10.isleaked.com/oldwindows.html
- http://www.pcworld.com/article/2998967/windows/how-to-block-the-windows-10-upgrade.html   ->   Watch for "Asok Smith"'s long comment
- http://www.infoworld.com/article/2907059/patch-management/microsoft-reissues-kb-2952664-win7-upgrade-pack-kb-2919355-win-81-update.html
- http://www.infoworld.com/article/3042155/microsoft-windows/windows-patch-kb-3139929-when-a-security-update-is-not-a-security-update.html -> relates to upgrade to W10 ads in IE 11 new tabs.
- [How to stop Microsoft from gathering telemetry data from Windows 7, 8, and 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/972501/how-to-stop-microsoft-from-gathering-telemetry-data-from-windows-7-8-and-8-1/)

Comment: what a mess! good job collecting all those x.link

Comment: you only need to block the GWX update KB3035583 and set the entry DisableOSUpgrade to 1. Blocking the other updates is not required

Comment: I still got GWX despite blocking KB3035583 in Windows 8.1

Comment: Why did you split up the KB numbers?

Comment: 3139929 no longer merely a suspect.  See http://www.infoworld.com/article/3042155/microsoft-windows/windows-patch-kb-3139929-when-a-security-update-is-not-a-security-update.html

Comment: @Mehrdad: It's easier to read by group when you have a huge list to check.

Comment: I wish there was a program to scan for the existing installed updates of the list above to uninstall them.

Comment: @X.LINK and harder for search engines to find? Thanks for the list anyway, still have to play 'spot the update'...

Answer (score 101):

Attempting to block the upgrade to Windows 10 by not installing certain updates is the incorrect approach of permanently preventing the upgrade to Windows 10.  By setting the `DisableOSUpgrade` registry key, you block the upgrade entirely, despite any prompts to upgrade.

As outline in this support article:  [How to manage Windows 10 notification and upgrade options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3080351)

> To block the upgrade to Windows 10 through Windows Update, specify the
>   following registry value:
>
> Subkey: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate
>
> DWORD value: DisableOSUpgrade = 1

In order to disable the Get Windows 10 notification icon do the following:

> For non-Enterprise versions of Windows, the notification icon can be
>   suppressed through the Windows registry. To do this, set the following
>   registry value:
>
> Subkey: HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Gwx
>
> DWORD value: DisableGwx = 1

It is worth pointing out the upgrade itself will automatically be blocked in the following condition:

> The computer or device is serviced through WSUS and has not had update
>   3035583 applied.

The group policy changes requires these updates:

[Windows Update Client for Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2: July 2015](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3065987)

[Windows Update Client for Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2: July 2015](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3065988)

Answer (score 15):

The following update will install GWX, which is the W10 upgrade nag and possible automatic install of W10 at some point.

1. [3035583](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3035583)

If you do not want additional Microsoft Telemetry or Spyware installed skip these also. Some below say they are for W8 but they showed up on a clean install of W7 recently.

2952664  (Compatibility update for upgrading Windows 7)

2976978   (WIndows 8, this is a W10 compatibility update)

2990214   (enables you to upgrade from Windows 7 to a later version of Windows)

3021917   (Telemetry)

3022345   (Update for customer experience and diagnostic telemetry)

3044374    (Update that enables you to upgrade from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10)

3068708   (Update for customer experience and diagnostic telemetry)

3075249   (Update that adds telemetry points to consent.exe in Windows 8.1 and Windows 7)

3080149   (Update for customer experience and diagnostic telemetry)

3123862   (Updated capabilities to upgrade Windows 8.1 and Windows 7)

3146449  (Part of 3139929) This update adds functionality to Internet Explorer 11 on some computers that lets users learn about Windows 10 or start an upgrade to Windows 10, [this adds a banner to IE11](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/16/03/10/1524238/patch-tuesday-brought-windows-10-ad-generator) to advertise windows 10

If GWX is already installed try this Free utility to get control of it

https://www.grc.com/never10.htm

Comment: may I ask what's the source? who says that those updates activate telemetry?

Comment: Google the kb numbers, Microsoft says so.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a started task in the task scheduler that can be disabled and the icon will go away.

it is located at: 
Task Scheduler Library - Microsoft - Windows - Setup - GWX and disable launchtrayprocess. log off/on and no more icon.

Comment: The thing is the icon isn't actually required to perform the upgrade to Windows 10.  There are actually multiple paths to download and start the upgrade but only permanently two paths will entirely prevent the upgrade.

Comment: Potentially not permanently....

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to avoid specific updates and to disable scheduled tasks. I've gone through this path and it's really too tedious, mainly because each month new crap related to Windows 10 is pushed and you have to start over again.

Instead, I suggest you to install all these updates, then use this little gem called [GWX Control Panel](http://blog.ultimateoutsider.com/2015/08/using-gwx-stopper-to-permanently-remove.html). No need for the "control panel", just use the standalone executable if you prefer. This way you have an easy, safe and exhaustive cleanup. And the updates are installed so you are not bothered by them again. Still, when new updates are pushed you'll have to run the tool again.

Comment: GWX is not required to upgrade to Windows 10

Comment: @ downvoters, yeah dealing with (literally) dozens of KBs is so more convenient. @Ramhound, I didn't get your point?

Comment: The author wants to block the upgrade all together on the system, the program you suggested, doesn't accomplish that goal.

Comment: You might want to give it another look, it explicitly disables upgrades as well. The only thing it lacks, maybe, are command line switches for script automation.

Comment: After reading the comments argument here, I went to the GWX Control PAnel site, read all the docs, and Ramhound is the correct one, GWX warns that it doesn't block KBs except a specific one, and that there are reports of Win7 resetting update settings, re-enabling auto-update (that GWX warns you that happened now, if you are on the PC), and installing the "force install Win10" update, all of this BECAUSE GWX wants to not block updates, thus your entire answer is incorrect Gras Double.

Comment: That's the point. KB are installed so you are not bothered by them again. After installing updates you have to run GWX again to disable the crap that is re-enabled by Win10-related updates.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating and running the following .reg file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
"DisableOSUpgrade"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Gwx]
"DisableGwx"=dword:00000001
```

Additionally, hiding KB3035583 whenever it is found in the Windows Update queue can be effective, but it seems to unhide itself frequently.