# Don't want Windows 10 upgrade - How do I stop installation

Tags: windows

Have a computer someone does NOT want window 10 upgrade. They accidentally hit upgrade...then turned off their computer. I restored to an earlier point to where I know they had not updated to 10. Restarted. Told windows not to install until I requested it. Now we get a RED notice Windows 10 upgrade failed. (which is good). Now when the computer is being shut down I think it is trying to upgrade (Message says installing 1 update). No idea what the update is. is there a way we can tell the computer NOT to install the one update? Checking the update list of what is to be updated, nothing is there, so I have NO actual idea of what it is, I am guessing Windows 10 is my best guess. If no solution, I guess I'll have to let windows 10 install and then restore it back to 7. I just don't want to waste the time. Thanks

Comment: use this tool to stop the Win10 upgrade: http://blog.ultimateoutsider.com/2015/08/using-gwx-stopper-to-permanently-remove.html

Comment: [By blocking it of course.](http://superuser.com/questions/1051187/what-are-every-windows-7-8-8-1-updates-kbs-i-must-skip-to-avoid-windows-10-upg/1051192#1051192)  There are other questions, with very good answers, that explain how to get out of the state our currently in.

Comment: This answer is showing high in Google.  Please link a "very good" answer that actually works.