# Windows 10 prompts on new computers

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, group-policy

Good morning.  Since I started here a lot of computers are getting Windows 10 prompts.  I have done everything I can think of to get rid of them but they continue to be a pest.  Here is what I have done:

Verified not in WSUS

Disable next Windows Upgrade in GPO is enabled

Set a specific Intranet location for updates in WSUS

Created the DisableGWX Key

Made sure computers are in correct category in Active Directory to apply GPO

When I check the computers 3035583 is installed.  I go through the uninstall and reboot but it continues to reinstall automatically.  WSUS does not have 3035583 listed and I cannot find it in the catalog either to download and decline it.  I dont know what to do from here.

Comment: Please [edit] and clarify your question. What "prompts" are you referring to? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @DavidPostill he is referring to the GWX icon in the bottom right system tray that prompts a "Upgrade to Windows 10 for Free!"

Comment: In order to stop GWX completely, you need to disable the Scheduled tasks found in Microsoft\Windows\Setup\GWX and GWXTrigger and rename the c:\windows\system32\GWX folder, then reboot. Do note, I had to use a program called GWXStopper because task scheduler claimed I did not have sufficient rights to disable the GWXTrigger tasks.

Comment: You are correct.  It is the GWX icon.  The user sometimes gets a window to upgrade to Windows 10 but says they cant do to Administrator Settings.

Comment: Dupe: [How to disable the "Get Windows 10" icon shown in the notification area (tray)?](http://superuser.com/q/922068) - read **all** the answers.

Comment: [Just block the update](http://superuser.com/questions/1051187/what-are-every-windows-7-8-8-1-updates-kbs-i-must-skip-to-avoid-windows-10-upg/1051192#1051192)

Comment: @DavidPostill Do you suggest that I delete my answer, since there is already a post that seem fairly complete?

Comment: @DaaBoss Up to you, but please read my comment under your answer if you decide to keep it.

Comment: Dupe: [What are every Windows 7/8/8.1 updates (KBs) I must skip to avoid Windows 10 upgrading -and nags-?](http://superuser.com/q/1051187)

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm adding a couple new articles, the link to these duplicate questions are much more complete:

> Dupe: [How to disable the "Get Windows 10" icon shown in the
> notification area (tray)?](https://superuser.com/questions/922068/how-to-disable-the-get-windows-10-icon-shown-in-the-notification-area-tray) - read all the answers. – DavidPostill 3
> hours ago
>
> Dupe: [What are every Windows 7/8/8.1 updates (KBs) I must skip to avoid Windows 10 upgrading -and nags-?](https://superuser.com/questions/1051187/what-are-all-the-windows-7-8-8-1-updates-kbs-i-must-skip-to-avoid-windows-10-u) – DavidPostill 1 hour ago

---

The Microsoft KB article below was referenced from this article:

[Latest IE Patch Might Be To Blame for Windows 10 Upgrade Ads - 03/10/2016](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2016/03/10/windows-10-upgrade-ads.aspx)
By Chris Paoli, the site producer for Redmondmag.com and MCPmag.com.
From RedmondMag:

> In a Microsoft blog post released late January, Matt Barlow, general
> manager of Xbox Marketing, also included a link for those shops that
> want to block the app from appearing on network-connected systems. He
> also promised that the GWX will not appear for large enterprises
> running Windows Enterprise edition or those that are using onsite
> system updating tools.

---

(Note that the KB link below: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3080351 appears to be broken in at least my version of Firefox.  I know it works in Edge.)

From MICROSOFT: March 15th, 2016
**[How to manage Windows 10 notification and upgrade options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3080351)**

> **Summary:**  Qualified computers and devices that are deployed in your organization and that are running Windows 7 Pro or Windows 8.1
> Pro are eligible for the free Windows 10 upgrade offer and will be
> able to upgrade through Windows Update. (This offer is not available
> to customers who are using Enterprise or Embedded editions of Windows
> 7 and Windows 8.1.) This article describes the notification and
> upgrade options, and it explains how you can manage these options.

Comment: You appear to have copied all of this answer from the link at the top of your post. This link, by the way, is **not** broken. Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing) and make sure you "block quote" quoted material ([Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help)), otherwise you may be accused of plagiarism.

Comment: @DavidPostill -- You are partially correct about the link, at least for me.  The link to Microsoft is NOT broken, but the redirect doesn't work with my current Firefox, but it does work with at least Edge.  My current plan is to leave the links and brief excerpts.  But, above that, reference the other two articles you mentioned, which are also helpful.  Please advise again and see if I got the right balance.  If not, I'll do whatever you suggest.  (Thanks for the block quote suggestion, and I will try to use that from now on, in addition to the link whenever I'm re-posting content)