# How to remove GWX permanently?

Tags: windows-7

I would like to know how I can *permanently* remove GWX from my machine. I am running Windows 7 currently, I have removed the `KB3035583` update, which did remove the system tray icon for a few days, but it has come back. According to the accepted answer in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/922068/how-to-disable-the-get-windows-10-icon-shown-in-the-notification-area-tray/922272#922272) question, removing the GWX directory may also be necessary, but I am not able to even though I am the admin, I get a message saying that I need permission from trustedinstaller, and cannot change permissions for some reason. I have also attempted this in Safe Mode with no luck.
  Is it something simple that I'm missing?

Comment: Boot into safe mode and you will be able to delete the folder

Comment: There's always the option of just waiting. The upgrade nagware is going to be disabled once the offer expires: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/05/06/windows_10_update/

Comment: [Just enabled the group policy](http://superuser.com/questions/1051187/what-are-all-the-windows-7-8-8-1-updates-kbs-i-must-skip-to-avoid-windows-10-u/1051192#1051192) or use [Never 10](https://www.grc.com/never10.htm) .  The update and GWX will be disabled.  Some additional steps must be taken to get rid of the data downloaded for the upgrade itself though.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://ultimateoutsider.com/downloads/   and download GWX control panel.
Gets rid of nags and will remove files, if they have already downloaded. Very easy to use.