# Windows update KB2952664 (Compattelrunner.exe) cannot be uninstalled from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, cpu-usage, migration

Update [KB2952664](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2952664):

> Compatibility update for upgrading Windows 7
>
> This update performs diagnostics on the Windows systems that
>   participate in the Windows Customer Experience Improvement Program.
>   These diagnostics help determine whether compatibility issues may be
>   encountered when the latest Windows operating system is installed.
>   This update will help Microsoft and its partners ensure compatibility
>   for customers who want to install the latest Windows operating system.

Said otherwise Microsoft uses your CPU and power to detect potential problems they may encounter if you move to Windows 10 (or if they force you to move to this version because it suits they agenda for not loosing against Google and Apple smartphones OSes).

They scan your files, and send the analysis to their servers. The problem is that users who "*participate in the Windows Customer Experience Improvement Program*" have seen their system slowed a lot with e.g. 70% CPU monopolized by the MS scanner, a program named `Compattelrunner.exe`. The latter can be launched on 100 or more concurrent threads.

[image]
<sup>(Source: [Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/how-do-i-prevent-microsoft-from-installing/0f82b270-7f94-403f-abfd-e738d8e5051e?auth=1))</sup>

At some point users want to stop being used as Microsoft's auxiliaries at their own expenses and discomfort.

The usual way to remove an update, and prevent it from reinstalling is (details on [Microsoft's site](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/troubleshoot-problems-removing-updates#1TC=windows-7):

- Switch Windows Update in manual mode
- Uninstall KB2952664
- Reboot
- Get new Windows updates
- In the new updates "hide" KB2952664.
- Switch Windows Update back to your usual mode.

Problem: In some cases this doesn't work. As soon as the system is rebooted, the KB2952664 update is reinstalled automatically, in spite of it being on the "hidden updates" list, *even if you are in manual mode*. Said otherwise it installs without your permission. Some have filled a complaint to the FTC (US [Federal Trade Commission](https://www.ftc.gov/)) to try and stop this:

> Microsoft updates install a program called compattelrunner.exe on my
>   computer without my authorization even though my update settings say,
>   "Download important updates but let me choose whether to install
>   them." Compattelrunner.exe serves no legitimate or beneficial purpose,
>   and causes serious performance problems (applications running slowly
>   or freezing up); I caught it on my computer this afternoon consuming
>   71% of my computer's CPU (central processing unit) capacity. I have
>   previo...

<sup>(Source: [Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/how-do-i-prevent-microsoft-from-installing/0f82b270-7f94-403f-abfd-e738d8e5051e?auth=1))</sup>

Question: Is there a way to get rid of the update, without it reinstalling at the next reboot?

---

<sup>I'm posting a solution, as I believe it will be useful for others in the same situation. There are many online endless posts and useless suggestions. This question and its solution should save time. Self-answered questions don't add to reputation, feel free to post better answers.</sup>

Comment: I always disable automatic install of updates, I set it to download updates but ask me when to install, and never had your issue using that setting, its the first setting I change on a new install, sorry I missed that in your question. Oh, I also deselect "give me recommended updates the same way i receive important updates"

Comment: @Moab: That's not relevant to the question, is it?

Comment: Actually it is but not going to argue about it.

Comment: It is said that the root of 99% of computer problems is between the chair and the monitor. And 99% of those affected people blame Microsoft instead! If this is happening on your computer, you have willingly opted in to CEIP. And now that `compattelrunner.exe` has found a problem and is trying to find a solution for it, you want to shoot the proverbial messenger. So, forgive me for not being positive that a US-FTC complaint goes anywhere. I have deployed this update to 66 Windows 7 computers via WSUS. But because none have opted in to CEIP, there has been no complaints.

Comment: Hmm... This question has been asked in 2016. But I am reading a release date of 10 April 2018 for this update. Maybe this is a newer version that just uses the same KB number.

Comment: Today MS is trying to install it again. I've seen it "offered" in two machines with this KB uninstalled, its previous "patches" hidden & opt-out of Customer Experience "Improvement" Program. So watch out.

Comment: Related: [How to stop Microsoft from gathering telemetry data from Windows 7, 8, and 8.1](https://superuser.com/q/972501/10259)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Symptoms**: It seems the Windows update is **reinstalled automatically** without your permission, in spite you prevented it, and stopped any automatic updates.

**Actual situation**: The update has been installed *multiple times* (possibly 10 times or more) each time with a new version number, removing it remove **only one version**.

**Solution**: Use **PowerShell** to list and remove versions.

If you really don't know what Powershell is, or don't have technical knowledge about Windows, then it's better you learn better going further. Powershell is a powerful tool to do anything on your filesytem and configuration, including harm. You need to use it with Administrator privileges, meaning you **won't have the usual system safety net**.

---

The solution comes from this Microsoft Community thread: [Unable to uninstall update KB2952664](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/unable-to-uninstall-update-kb2952664/1c0e8b8a-c79b-4998-b6be-f8134cef4e82).

Launch PS with administrator rights.

List installed versions of the update:

```
dism /online /get-packages | findstr KB2952664
```

Remove one by one the versions:

```
dism /online /remove-package /PackageName:Package_for_KB2952664~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.3
```

Confirm everything is gone:

```
 Get-HotFix -id KB2952664
```

It should display a `cannot find hot-fix` *error*.

Comment: A note: When I tried this, I had to apply them in order starting from the bottom, or I got "access denied" errors.

Comment: Maybe someone could make a small tool with just one big button saying "Get rid of Windows Customer Experience Improvement Program".

Comment: After these steps and rebooting, Windows Update offers it to me again  under "Important updates". I hide it and... it appears again under "Optional updates"!

Comment: You don't need `PowerShell`, do you?. `dism` works from command line and, to confirm the result, you can just reuse the `findstr` command.

Comment: @cdlvcdlv: Oh, six months later you are still dealing with this issue?

Comment: After installing a monthly rollup Windows 7 never booted again and I couldn't find out why (I tried everything I found googling to no avail) so I reinstalled.

Comment: It's stunning how many times MS tries to install it. Look [what I found](https://justpaste.it/1g8af) in a machine.

Answer (score 36):

A simpler way to stop the CPU usage is to disable the `Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser` task in [Task Scheduler](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721931.aspx) under `\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience`.

Comment: Why would I use a bypass when there is a known solution? Disabling is not the solution to remove an application that was installed multiple times. Uninstalling it is possible, see selected answer.

Comment: because Windows update will offer it again and here you have to skip/hide it all time. so simply disable the execution is the faster way to get rid of it

Comment: I think the service might automatically re-enable itself in Windows 10, I'm pretty sure I disabled every service under /Microsoft/Windows/Application Experience and today I checked it and it's back and enabled again.

Answer (score 4):

From my blog http://nonsumhircum.livejournal.com/883.html, 
you need to stop "participating in the Windows Customer Experience Improvement Program", which you can do (for W7 & W8) when running as admin, by:

1. Start the control panel and click Action Center > Change Action Center settings.
2. Click Customer Experience Improvement Program settings.
3. Select No, I don't want to participate in the program and click Save changes.

Next, disable the scheduled tasks, thus:

1. Start the control panel and click Administrative Tools > Task Scheduler.
2. In the Task Scheduler (Local) pane of the Task Scheduler dialog box, expand the Task Scheduler Library > Microsoft > Windows nodes and open the Application Experience folder:

   - Disable the AITAgent and ProgramDataUpdater tasks:
3. In the Task Scheduler Library > Microsoft > Windows node, open the Customer Experience Improvement Program folder.

   - Disable the Consolidator, KernelCEIPTask, and UsbCEIP tasks.

Obviously disabling the above means you don't get the benefits of being in the WCEI Program(me).

Comment: @Ramhound My answer will help removal and prevent auto re-installation.  Feel free to move it to a comment if you prefer - I thought it might be too long for that.

Comment: Should `Use CEIP` be `UsbCeip` actually?

Comment: @superjos  Yes, thanks, took me a while to notice your comment.

Comment: I had selected the "No, I don't want..." but the system took no notice of it. Just out of curiosity, what are "the benefits of being in the WCEI Program"? Could you provide an MS page listing such benefits? For the only difference I can attest is the hogging of my CPU (the origin of my attention to this process), what I'd hardly describe as a benefit.

Comment: Actually VMWare has the same info https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-7/7.0/com.vmware.horizon-view.desktops.doc/GUID-BE82165B-13BC-4FD9-A9CF-FBEF6343D98A.html

Answer (score 2):

Using PowerShell with elevated privileges, you can disable **Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser** with the following command:

```
Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser" -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience"
```

Comment: Thanks for the command. However wanted to uninstall KB2952664, not disable it.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that. I guess I was blinded by the cpu issue :-)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe related ot not, but i was experiencing near the same but not in CPU, it was I/O and arround 1h30'.

The cause was near similar, same place on Task Schedule, but different task.

Under `\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience` there are three (on my case) tasks: `Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser`, `ProgramDataUpdater` and `StartupAppTask`

I had first and second `Disabled` but third was `Enabled`, and seen last time execution i can see it runs more than once on each reboot.

Also i could see it running for one hour and a half on each reboot, making all I/O to disk be very hard for other apps, so computer was really slow.

I have also `Disabled` the third one, so now all three are `Disabled` and the I/O problem on each reboot just disapear.

Now my PC can be used in less than a minute, instead of having to wait more than ninty (90) minutes, yes one hour and thirty minutes; that is a great win!

Notes:

- The start time of that task represents the last run on each reboot and in my case is near two hours after reboot (in the meantime that time is changing some times, so i can see it runs more than once on each reboot).
- `ProgramDataUpdater` and `StartupAppTask` has no triggers, but when they are enabled they are run on each reboot
- The value of `StartupAppTask` last time run is updated on each reboot near ten times or more, and after two hours since reboot seems not to be launched again
- After disable all three tasks, Windows starts without 100% I/O and can be used in less than a minute, having any of them enabled the I/O at starts goes for 1.5 hours or more, so i can not do anything on that time, except wait for it to finish.

So my solution is to disable all tasks under `\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience`; sorry M$, but i will not allow you to use my PC on each reboot for near two hours, when i power it on i need to use it, i can not wait each time so much time!

Comment: "Application *Experience*": This kind of sentence like "user experience" or "service improvement" often hides behind a vague teaser the real purpose of obtaining from you something you really wouldn't want to give if you took time to read the license. 90 minutes, it could be a world record :(

Answer (score 0):

It was the CompatTelRunner.exe that was crashing my 8 Gig PC 4 CPU each startup after 3 minutes.  I created a batch loop that swats their bug with > taskkill /T /F /IM CompatTelRunner.exe each 8 seconds by CHOICE delay.  That saved my PC from repeated Microsoft induced crashes(Blue Screens) to my Hard Drive.

"CompatTelRunner.exe","3472","Services","0","3,736 K","Unknown","NT AUTHORITY\SYSTE
"CompatTelRunner.exe","3500","Services","0","43,852 K","Unknown","NT 
Killing Suspect Tasks -
SUCCESS: The process with PID 3500 (child process of PID 3472) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 3472 (child process of PID 564) has been terminated.

I now used the disables of Experience Tasks posted above ( From http://nonsumhircum.livejournal.com/883.html ) to see if I can now stop my task swatter too.

Comment: Signatures are unnecessary noise and shouldn't be included in answers

Answer (score 0):

Based on **mins** answer, this is my one-liner version of the big button saying "Get rid of Windows Customer Experience Improvement Program":

1. Open a Command prompt with administrator privileges.
2. Copy the following insane line, paste it on the Command Prompt window and press Enter.

   `` @for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %a in (`dism /online /get-packages^|findstr KB2952664`) do @(@set "pckgnm=%a"&@call start "" /b /wait dism /norestart /online /remove-package /PackageName:%pckgnm:~1%&@set pckgnm=) ``
3. If the machine is slow or you do this for the first time, it's likely  [going to last a long while](https://superuser.com/a/1325255/607984).
4. With the `/norestart` option, you will not be prompted to restart if needed, so you should just in case. Time for <strike>point-threeing your life</strike> <strike>more point-threeing</strike> more point 3(?).
5. Anyway, check that all the "updates" are gone. Right after the insane command if you answered `n` or when/if you return if you answered `y`. (Remember you can do the 3 again.)

   `dism /online /get-packages | findstr KB2952664`
6. Enjoy your a-little-less-bloated system.
7. I'll suppose you have the system not configured to install automatically updates. From time to time MS will "offer" you to install a new version of this "hotfix". From my experience (see the comments to **mins** answer), just after uninstalling them, it appeared again in important hotfixes and, when I hid it reappeared in optional updates. After that, I've seen this KB number appear several times. You must remember it or part of the number to avoid  reinstalling.