# Windows 10 summons rundll32 after install something

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1511

I've noticed that every time I install something, `rundll32.exe` runs and it takes up 99% of my disk resource, which makes my computer slow. This is the command that is run:

```
rundll32.exe aeinv.dll,UpdateSoftwareInventory
```

I have to end it manually from task manager, and everything goes well even though I ended a system process.

Does anyone know what has caused this? How would I disable it?

Comment: Rundll does nothing by itself. Without the entire command line, it’s not clear which function in which DLL is called.

Comment: In Task Manager, select the `Details` tab, right-click on a column header and click `Select Columns`. Enable `Command line` checkbox. Now Task Manager should show you the complete command-line parameters for every process. See which DLL is being run by `rundll32.exe`.

Comment: `rundll32.exe aeinv.dll,UpdateSoftwareInventory` is the command.

Comment: perhaps [this](http://www.eightforums.com/performance-maintenance/44709-windows-host-process-rundll32-high-cpu-usage.html) can explain (it's windows 8.1, but I assume it would still apply to Windows X)

Answer (score 4):

The `aeinv.dll` is a dll for application compatibility. The `UpdateSoft‌​wareInventory` command scans your Windows for the installed applications and sends them as telemetry to Microsoft if you are part of the `Customer Experience Improvement Program`. Microsoft uses it to see which combination of software is used by people to minimize compatibility issues.

Comment: I have `Customer Experience Improvement Program` participation disabled but am still seeing the reported behavior for ~5 minutes (on average) after an install or upgrade.

Comment: @apraetor this task runs even if you disabled the Customer Experience Improvement Program. But here no data are send to MS. You can disalbe this task in taskmgr

Comment: Task Manager? Not Task Scheduler? I see 4 tasks in task scheduler, which all say they don't run if CEIP participation is disabled -- but also show they've run in the past 4 days... BthSQM ("error in the DLL"), Consolidator, KernelCeipTask, UsbCeip. Are you referring to the Services tab in Task Scheduler?

Comment: @apraetor yeah, task scheduler: http://superuser.com/a/1069212/174557

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem for quite a time as well and didn't know what to do, until I found an answer in another [forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/4p4eyk/high_cpu_usage_with_rundll32_aeinvdll_update/d743knp) and that helped me!

You can disable the "**Program Compatibility Assistant Service**", as it appears to be this service that summons the `aeinv.dll,UpdateSoftwareInventory`. If you want to be sure, disable the "**Customer Experience Improvement Program**" as well. I tested it myself and it worked for me, `aeinv.dll` is no longer being summoned from the depths of hell to consume my computer resources!