# Why CompatTelRunner is running while participate in CEIP is set to no?

Tags: windows-10

Participation in Windows Customer Experience Improvement Program (CEIP) is set to "No, I don't want to participate in the program." However, Windows Compatability Telemetry (CompatTelRunner.exe) is running.

(Currently, I disabled \Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser in the Task Scheduler.)

Should CompatTelRunner run while participate in CEIP is set to no in Windows 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting doesn't prevent the run of the `CompatTelRunner.exe`, it only prevents that the collected telemetry is actually send to Microsoft after collecting them.

You already did the correct thing to stop the run [by disabling the scheduled task](https://superuser.com/a/1069212/174557).

Comment: What is the reason of collecting data without sending them?

Comment: @TN. I have no idea. Send it as feedback in the feedback hub, so that Microsoft updates the CompatTelRunner.exe to first check if CEIP is enabled and if not, stop running CompatTelRunner.exe.

Answer (score -1):

While the first answer is correct still everybody wants to know how to stop it. So, find the compattelrunner.exe. Right click, Properties, security, down you'll have to press advanced and you'll see Owner: and the name of the owner, I think it is Trustedinstall (I just deleted it so that's why it's "I think"). You'll have to change it so you press Change near the name.  Than down left you'll see Advanced again. Press it and you'll see on the right "Find now". Press that and find your account name (it can be another one, just not Trustinstall). Now press ok and ok...until you are out. Go back again (and here is the catch) and again in security, advanced you'll see all the permissions. There press change permissions than press to your account name or "administrator" (if it's like that) and change to full control (the access, I double clicked on the names I think, but you can google how to change to full control), but most just delete the trustedinstall and guest from the list so they don't have acces anymore (I changed first to just read and view for access for the trustedinstal) The thing with that removal is that now I had full access to delete the file (before that it told me I need access from the administrator although I was the one...) Good luck!