# CompaTTelRunner.exe uses almost all cpu

Tags: windows-10, memory, cpu-usage, high-cpu-usage

So this has been going on for a while. I will suddenly get 1 or more CompatTelRunner.exe. I am aware of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1069174/windows-update-kb2952664-compattelrunner-exe-cannot-be-uninstalled-from-window) question and its answers.

Why would it be using so much of the CPU and RAM (last time it happened it used 4gb of RAM and 80% CPU)? And why would I get more than one of these processes(8 last time)?

Comment: the tool scans the PC for all installed software. Ask Microsoft why they use so much CPU. disable the task to stop it