# High CPU usage on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cpu

My Windows 10 CPU Usage is always very high, near 100%. Usually it is the Antimalware program.
[image]

So, I end the program because I don't need it, but my CPU continues to be at 100%.

[image]
How can I fix this?

---

Update: This is what's taking up my cpu now...
[image]

---

System Information:
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55601/discussion-on-question-by-suomynona-high-cpu-usage-on-windows-10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looking at the ETL with WPA](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis), shows several issues:

- Superfetch Service causes high CPU usage by its function `sysmain.dll!PfPdLogEntryProcessHelper`:

[image]

- Now `TiWorker.exe` (Trusted Instaler Worker) tries to resume to download an update and also extracts and moves the data

[image]

- Also the Kernel causes high CPU usage by also doing Prefetch Operations like Superfetch

[image]

- Now the new [Memory Compression of Windows 10](https://superuser.com/a/952142/174557) causes CPU usage by compressing memory

[image]

- next the `CompatTelRunner.exe` scans your PC for installed software, which causes CPU usage. To stop it, [disable the scheduled task](https://superuser.com/a/1069212/174557).

What I see in several processes are DriverVerifier related calls

> **Verifier**Ext.sys!IofCallDriver_internal_wrapper

,

> ntoskrnl.exe!**Vi**FilterDispatchGeneric

[Disable driver Verifier](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5470-driver-verifier-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) to speedup Windows. It should also lower the side effects in all other processes.

Comment: CPU is lower now; antimalware service executable and microsoft compatibility telemetry are the only two problems i see now

Comment: Defender is always slow. Use a 3rd party anti virus suite. have you disabled the scheduled task?

Comment: There are a lot of them, dont know which one to disable. I reinstalled malwarebytes though, so I think defender will disable on its own. Also what about the microsoft compatibility telemetry?

Comment: disable all tasks under Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience in taskscheduler

Comment: I did it, should be ok now?

Comment: yes. it should be better now. Monitor the usage over the next days