# Periodical performance drops and high HDD usage Windows10

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, performance

Usually my system performs fine. However, periodically, there are temporary performance drops. Basically the Task Manager shows 100% HDD usage and the culprits invariably turn out to be system related processes like:

- `MsMpEng.exe` Antimalware Service Executable
- `AppXSvc` AppX Deployment Service (AppXSVC)
- `svchost.exe` Service Host: Superfetch
- `ntoskrnl.exe` System
- `CompatTelRunner.exe` Microsoft Compatibility Telemetry
- And others.

I don't what is Windows doing - scanning my computer for threats with Windows Defender, downloading and installing updates, defragging HDD - but whatever it is I hope its not going kill my HDD anytime soon and can Windows please do all of this while I'm afk and certainly not when I play League of Legends!

I can't help but notice Linux Mint doesn't experience these periodical performance drops. This persists for a few years already, I'm frankly fed up with this.

Can anything be done to alleviate this issue?

Comment: Reopened ......

Comment: [CompatTelRunner.exe](https://superuser.com/a/1069212/174557) causes it. follow my link and disable the task

Answer (score 0):

In all of my experience, majority of the time SuperFetch is the culprit for hard drive slow downs.

Here is a guide on how to disable SuperFetch.
https://www.technipages.com/windows-enable-disable-superfetch

You shouldnt have any issues come up after disabling it.

Comment: You should quote and cite the relevant information from your link.  See the associated meta.su question and help center for reasons why a link-only answer isn't helpful to the community.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief overview of Superfetch and how it can impact performance if you're using an HDD instead of an SSD:

https://itechbeat.com/service-host-superfetch-windows/

There is also a section showing how to disable it as a service if it's causing trouble. I don't know if this is the source of your issue, but I hope it helps, nonetheless.

Usually, when I've had slowness issues, it's a combination of Superfetch continuing to run at the same time an A/V was trying to access the disk (Sophos, Avast, ESET, all of these). When they would start running together, you'd see 100% Disk usage, between 20 - 30% CPU and over 50% Memory usage