# Privacy. Prevent data gathered by microsoft on local computer to be upload

Tags: privacy

In his answer to "[How to stop Microsoft from gathering telemetry data from Windows 7, 8, and 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/972501/how-to-stop-microsoft-from-gathering-telemetry-data-from-windows-7-8-and-8-1)", "DavidPostill" suggested to block appropriate hosts on the broadband router to prevent uploading telemtry data to microsoft collected by updates or other.

Does this mean, before installation no more evaluation is needed about updates to be telemetry or not because the data is in any case prevented to upload to microsoft? If this is the case, i assume no more effort is needed to prevent microsoft from gathering data on the local computer because it can not be uploaded.

Thx for assistance.

Comment: I recommend disabling the telemetry agents as best you can, in addition to network blocking. MS can throw up a new server on a new url and get your box to send telemetry to it without any real difficulty, so just blocking at the network will be committing yourself to a never ending game of Wack-a-Mole.

Comment: Blocking hosts is only a partial solution. You need to take in account all of the relevant (to your OS) steps outlined in the answer. Note that that answer was as accurate as I could make it the time of writing (9 months ago) and things may now need even more tweaking ... there may be additional updates that need to be blocked/removed for example.

Comment: Thank you Frank and David for clarifying. I actually feel very uncomfortable concerning privacy.