# Unable to disable Compatibility Telemetry in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, privacy, spyware, telemetry

***Methods Failed to disable Microsoft Compatibility Telemetry:***

**Method 1:** Use [O&O ShutUp10](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10) <sub>Used latest version released on 7-Mar-'17</sub>

**Method 2** (CMD commands) <sub>mentioned [here](https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-disable-microsoft-compatibility-telemetry-compattelrunner-exe/)</sub> **:**

```
sc delete DiagTrack
sc delete dmwappushservice
echo "" > C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Diagnosis\ETLLogs\AutoLogger\AutoLogger-Diagtrack-Listener.etl
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection" /v AllowTelemetry /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

**Method 3** (Disable appraiser) <sub>mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/a/1069212/371227)</sub> **:** Disable the *Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser* task in Task Scheduler under **`\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience`**.

**Method 4** (Disable all tasks under **`\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience`**) <sub>mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1188291/unable-to-disable-compatibility-telemetry-in-windows-10#comment1723753_1188291)</sub> **:** Disabled all tasks (*Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser*, *ProgramDataUpdater*, *StartupAppTask*) under **`\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience`**.

---

Microsoft Compatibility Telemetry is known for its high disk and CPU usage and suspicious anti-privacy activities.

I've used the previous methods to disable it but all of them failed to disable it, as it returns to run again.

[image: Task Manager]

Moreover, weird activity was detected via [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) where Compatibility Telemetry is trying to write files to my antivirus location.
Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: It returns showing up in Task Manager

Comment: .Smart quotes `“”` are invalid in batch files

Comment: I haven't run them as smart quotes, I ran them directly from CMD window as `""`.

Comment: disable the **Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser** task in task scheduler: https://superuser.com/a/1069212/174557

Comment: @magicandre1981 I tried it and Microsoft Compatibility Telemetry returned to work.

Comment: disable all the Compatibility tasks in task scheduler

Comment: @magicandre1981 What are they or where are they located in task scheduler?

Comment: disable all tasks under **Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience**

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've tried it and Microsoft Compatibility Telemetry returned to work.

Comment: also delete the tasks if disabling doesn't stop them

Comment: Do you run automatic windows update? It seems that on my computer it came back at the same time I did the Windows 10 Creator Update. Maybe it overwrites previous settings. Since re-disabling it, it didn't showed up again yet. I follow the Windows10Club page to do that. http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-telemetry

Comment: Same here :( did you find a solution?

Comment: Ok. I have an idea. Right click and show command line. If it isn't what it should be for the program, you may have a virus.

Comment: I confirm that none of the potential solutions mentioned here works since Creator's Update. I'm contemplating writing a small tool that will monitor the list of running processes and just terminate this annoyance.

Comment: I want to point out that use of CreateFile function doesn't necessarily imply write operation. If OP will be analyzing program activity in the future using e.g. Procmon, it is good to know that CreateFile can be used for reading too. Key point is `Desired Access` column, which OP hid in the screenshot. Looking few lines down, we see use of ReadFile, which probably used file handle obtained from CreateFile function. Further reading in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540534(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop Microsoft from gathering telemetry data from Windows 7, 8, and 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/972501/how-to-stop-microsoft-from-gathering-telemetry-data-from-windows-7-8-and-8-1)

Answer (score 7):

I had similar problem in my laptop, the telemetry consumes all disk IOs after I install anything new or updates. Making it unusable for a few hours.

Here how I solved:

1. Make sure the telemetry is not running (you can stop it from the task manager)
2. Open your %windir%\system32\
3. Find the trouble maker CompatTelRunner.exe
4. Gain ownership on the file (Properties -> security tab -> advanced -> owner change, set yourself as owner)
5. Add permission to modify for the users (select "users" -> edit -> basic permissions-> check modify -> ok)
6. Click ok again
7. Rename the CompatTelRunner.exe to CompatTelRunner.exe.bak for example

The telemetry will not run any more. until you restore the windows or a major windows update.

PS:This solution might generate some error log entries.Because windows will still trying to run it.

Comment: [It's not that easy](https://borncity.com/win/2017/02/22/windows-10-execute-programs-as-systemtrustedinstaller/) to change the access rights on a TrustedInstaller owned binary, unfortunately. Also, strangely enough, when I tried running a third party Explorer clone (because explorer.exe is hard coded to never start as TrustedInstaller / Administrator) CompatTelRunner was no longer listed in C:\Windows\System32! It didn't show up in cmd either. I wasn't able to find a way to rename CompatTelRunner.

Comment: Are you a local admin in your machine? @jrh

Comment: Yes I am a local admin

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll have to do this after every windows update.