# Powershell script to remove Windows CEIP patches?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, powershell

Recently I read  [How to stop Microsoft from gathering telemetry data from Windows 7, 8, and 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/972501/how-to-stop-microsoft-from-gathering-telemetry-data-from-windows-7-8-and-8-1)

I wonder it would be great if there is powershell script that can be executed and do all that (Disabling Telemetry through patch removal method, I prefer).

Unfortunately I don't know anything much about powershell script yet.
So I wonder if it's possible to convert and any coders here might wanna convert the solution at the above link into powershell therefore to make easier to run/execute.
Your help will be much appreciated. Thx

Comment: @Biswa Thx. That was sum potentially good stuff. Unfortunately, I didn't really understand them without readin the desc. and those weren't what I am lookin for. All I was looking for was script to run the `wusa \uninstall ...`. And I hvn't executed them too becoz I don't know (not sure) what it will do to my machine lol. Once i got my test machine, i'll prob try see. But modifying the firewall is not what i was trying to achieve. But Thx

Comment: You can disable or delete the Windows update service with `sc` command.