# How does one Blacklist a patch based on Knowledge Based/KB number?

Tags: windows-7, windows, malware

I installed two updates today on a Windows 7 machine. One was KB3035583, which was purported to fix problems with Windows. The other was a malware definitions update.

KB3035583 turned out to be Microsoft's Marketing Malware known as [Get Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/922068). It did not fix anything, it misrepresented itself to get installed, and it has created problems (*q.v.*).

In the old days, we could set kill bits on Active X controls that were effectively malware or dangerous. I'd like to include KB3035583 in a similar list on this machine and my other test machines.

How does one Blacklist a patch based on Knowledge Based/KB number?

Comment: On Windows 7, you can right-click on the update and click 'Hide Update'. I'm sure there's a way to do it in the registry, but I'm sure that's unneeded. Also, for future reference, any update beginning with `KB3` is for Windows 10 as far as I know. Sorry I cannot be of more help, but that's all I can suggest in hopes of solving your issue easily, though I can see from your profile that you're beyond me in experience.

Comment: The problem with ***`Hide Update`*** is it goes away if you delete `...\System32\SoftwareDistribution\*`. Doing so recovers 100's of MBs to GBs; and it clears the history in control panel. I do it frequently.

Comment: How about this one then: [/722667/how-to-hide-updates-in-windows-updates-without-gui](http://superuser.com/questions/722667/how-to-hide-updates-in-windows-updates-without-gui)? I've also been seeing things about a program named "WSUS"... consider looking into that?